# Notation for set of unit vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vectors

Is there a standard notation for the set of unit vectors $\{\vec v\ :\ |\vec v|=1\}$?

Comment: Is this relative to a specific vector space, or *any* vector space with an appropriate norm?

Comment: Right now I'm writing up something on $\Bbb R^n$, but if there's a notation for other spaces, that'd be good to know as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In $\mathbb R^n$, it is common to use $S^{n-1}$ to denote $\{v \in \mathbb R^n : ||v|| = 1\}$.

Comment: typesetting comment, `\|v\|` makes the lines closer together.  compare $\|v\|$ and $||v||$